# Submitting a Certificate Signing Request for Approval

Tags: iphone, ios

I've looked at the "How To" docs provided in the Provisioning portal and under the "Submitting a Certificate Signing Request for Approval" link. It says that by clicking on Certificates > Development I can upload the CSR for approval but when I click on Certificates > Development I only can view the "Current Development Certificates" and "Team Signing Requests (0)".

Why can't I find a way to upload a CSR in the Provisioning Portal, Could it be that I dont have the right permissions I am using the companies login to the portal as they want the app to be submitted through their account. 
The member I'm logging in with is the team agent (apparently), could this be causing the problem or is there something else i'm missing?

Thanks
Brett

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your are login with the team agent credentials you see your team agent's development certificate. Because this certificate has not expire yet, you cannot upload a new CSR to create a new certificate. You have three different options to solve this problem, I will order them from the best to the worst :

1. Ask your team agent to register you as a new team member and, after login with your new credentials, create your own development certificate.
2. Download your team agent's development certificate and ask your team agent to export his development private key for you in order to use the certificate properly.
3. Revoke you team agent's development certificate and create a new one. You will have to export your new certificate and your new private key to other members of your team.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, it's exactly the info I needed, all is working now.